# Spring boot DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor causes potential memory leak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, tomcat9

In a spring boot app (2.1.4-RELEASE) when using the following configuration of a TaskExecutor

```
  @Primary
  @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Foo-");
    executor.initialize();

    return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
  }
```

when shutting down tomcat (9.0.19) I get the following warning.

```
02-May-2019 10:34:07.384 WARNUNG [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [myapp#bar] appears to have started a thread named [Foo-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:194)
 java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
 java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:433)
 java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The warning disappears when the DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor is removed:

```
  @Primary
  @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
  @Bean
  public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Foo-");
    executor.initialize();

    return executor;
  }
```

What is the cause? How can that be solved?

**Update:** I excuse (please don't stone me) but I completely forgot that it is a spring boot app which is being deployed as an exploded war in the tomcat. I now tried as well tomcat version 9.0.17 which is used by Spring 2.1.4.RELEASE but same problem. When starting the spring boot by itself then the problem does not appear.

**Update2:** Opened a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6837)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give another name to your thread pool executor.
You are attributing your settings to Springs default thread pool executor hence even the springs on thread executor is Async now.

> @Primary
>   @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskExecutor")

instead define your own

```
  @Primary
  @Qualifier("appThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
```

Comment: That didn't help. I made sure all corresponding places match the new Qualifier name.